# How to customize the "sections" representations with graphical shapes?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to have "sections" in which not to have numbers, instead to have some custom graphical artworks next to them. I want them to appear the same in the table of contents. Like the following figure:

[image]

In the figure above, my "section" has a graphical artwork (a simple circle here) next to it (without any numberings), which I want it also to be appear the same in the table of contents (with `hyperref`package for example). I don't mind if the chapter and/or the sub-sections and/or sub-sub-sections to have numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick hack, not really customizable so far...

Redefine `\@seccntformat` for `\section`, this displays the section number in the section header and add some change for `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tikz}



\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}{%
    \shapecircle%
  }{%
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad%
  }%
}


\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\shapecircle[0.15]}%
    \fi
    #7}}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}%
}{}{}

\makeatother


\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}



\DeclareRobustCommand{\shapecircle}[1][0.2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \shade[ball color=red] (0,0) circle(1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}





\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\section{Foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your best answer, but when I'm using `‎\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}‎` it's not working well in table of contents. I don't know why?

Comment: @Gahir: Load `hyperref` after the patches done to `\@sect`, see the updated example

Comment: Thank you very much, you answered my question completely.